# Не могу исполнить файл .class из консоли

Tags: java

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Есть программа, которая выводит *"Hello world"*.
Удачно скомпилировал ее через консоль с помощью команды *-javac*, однако не могу исполнить получившийся байт-код. Консоль пишет, что не может найти файл с таким именем (разрешение *.class* при запуске удалял, не работает).

Comment: А как выглядит ваша команда для запуска?

Comment: java Main (класс Main.class)

Comment: Компиляция точно успешно проходит? файл Main.class появился?

Answer (score 3):

в Java есть такая штука называется `CLASSPATH` - то есть это место где Java будет искать классы.

Вам нужно написать что-то типа:

```
java -cp . Main //опция cp задает что Main.class в текущем каталоге
```

В более общем надо писать так:

```
java -cp [путь к class файлу или jar] <имя пакета>.MyClass
```

Comment: Можно подробнее пожалуйста. Пробовал написать java -cp . Main - ничего не выходит.

Comment: надо запускать с каталога где лежит Main.class

Comment: Так я же так и делаю.

Comment: Покажите трассировку ошибки, которую выдает Java

Comment: И еще в каком пакете находится ваш Main.java? Если быть точнее покажите декларацию `package` вашего класса

Comment: Проблему удалось решить, если не писать package по умолчанию и написать java -cp . Main. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запускать из каталога класса так javac ./имя_файла (без расширения)